# Angular ng-repeat unused warning

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning angular js, I'm trying some examples and I'm getting unused warning from netbeans. When I run the file in browser it doesn't show anything but from the tutorial I'm watching it works, it doesn't work on my side. here is the code.

```
<html ng-app>
 ...
<div ng-controller="test">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{ cust.name }}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
<script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function test($scope){
       $scope.customers = [
            {name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix'},
            {name: 'Jamie Riley', city: 'Atlanta'},
            {name: 'Heedy Wahlin', city: 'Chandler'},
            {name: 'Thomas Winter', city: 'Seattle'}
            ];
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vhoy1s7/1/)

console errors.
[image]

Comment: Try loading the angular library after your script

Comment: @MarounBaydoun I tried that doesn't work.

Comment: On the fiddle you provide, it works if you load the angular library at the end of the body. What version of angular are you using?

Comment: @MarounBaydoun 1.4.3

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: yes, I have included screenshot showing errors, in my question.

Comment: It's working fine in the fiddle, I just changed `Frameworks & Extensions` to `No wrap in body`

Comment: So what's happening is that the angular app is firing up before your own script has been parsed. So i suggest using the proper angular way of creating app as a module and then adding the controllers to that module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add no wrap in body in js fiddle

Like this

[image]

try to use angular in proper way

like this

**view**

```
<html ng-app="app">
<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <!-- do something -->
  </div>
  <script src="your angular library file path"></script>
  <script src="app.js path"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("myCtrl",["$scope",function($scope){
   // put your code
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks working on jsfiddle, how can i make this work in my html file.

Comment: put libary file in body tag after `<div ng-app></div>`

Comment: the one in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The same error also arise due to duplicate keys. There you can use track by $index

```
<ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers track by $index">{{ cust}}</li>
        </ul>
```